# Actual sizeof padded struct, (sum of member sizes, without padding for alignment)

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-2010, gcc

**sizeof**() returns **size of structure including padding** of members for alignment. Which is fine. Don't need to pack the structure to have 0 padding.

Just need to get get(or calculate) sum of sizes of members of structure to compare (using it in **static compile time assert**).

When you have members small in size, they absence/difference is not get caught. 
Members are mainly char arrays

Is it possible to get that number at compile time (or at run time)?

Or how else can I make sure the 'effective' size is what I expect and avoid accidental change from braking the program?

Original intention is to avoid bugs if A or B modified to be different by mistake. 
Using STATIC_ASSERT( **sizeof(A) == sizeof(B)** )
which doesn't work for some 'small' differences due to padding.

note: A and B should be similar, but in given design it's not possible to reuse A in both parts of the program. This check is to make sure if someone changes only A or only B, it can not compiled.

Comment: Even if you know how much is devoted to padding, it would only be safe to use memcmp if all the padding was at the end of the object, which is not guaranteed. If you want memcmp to be safe, using whatever #pragma packing options and/or static asserts to guarantee that there is *no* padding in your struct, and pad it yourself if alignment is required.

Comment: I think memcmp is for comparing content. I'm comparing types. And I can not and do not want to change default packing.

Comment: One way would be to define a macro that declares a packed version of a struct and does whatever assert you want. Only affects compile time.

Comment: What size do you "expect" ?

Comment: What is the root problem you are trying to solve here?  When you're asking how to do something this obscure / abnormal, there is a good chance there's a better solution to your problem and you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: Also: What's your actual compiler platform? VS? GCC? Both?  Do you need a portable solution?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I expect it to be equal to the size of similar struct declared elsewhere. Using same type is not possible in this case

Comment: @BrianMcFarland Trying to put   STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof(A) == sizeof(B)).  But because of padding, small differences are not detected by this.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland  Development is in Visual Studio 2010, C code. Will be compilable under AIX (GCC) too, but having it work under the Studio is enough ... if it is compile time

Comment: @AlanAu the point is to use existing declarations. to not have even more copies of definitions of types. Is it possible to only typedef a new struct type from existing and make the new one have different packing?

Comment: You still haven't explained why you need the size of the unpacked type.

Comment: If two structs have the same definition then they will have the same size (unless you use different compiler options or pragmas, which causes undefined behaviour).

Comment: @sny No, you can't put the packed attribute in a typedef. But you can #include the same header twice. Once with packed enabled and once without. And obviously the macro would also change the name of the packed struct  to something different to the real struct name. I can't post code properly here in the comments. I think you can work it out. But if it sounds like it could work for you and you need an example let me know and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @AlanAu Thank you Alan. Seems like I can work it out, (I'm in release stage of another projectj. No time for it now though. Number of structs is small. Manually verifying) If you put some example I will be able to mark it as answer. Or I will do it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can #include the same header twice. Once with packed enabled and once without. And obviously the macro would also change the name of the packed struct to something different to the real struct name.

Here's an example. The header file, say test.h, is shown below. It shows two struct which have different unpacked sizes but same packed sizes.

```
#ifdef ENABLE_PACKED
#define PACKED(x) __attribute__ ((__packed__)) x##_packed
#else
#define PACKED(x) x
#endif

struct PACKED(my_struct1) {
    char c1;
    int i1;
    char c2;
    int i2;
};

struct PACKED(my_struct2) {
    char c1;
    char c2;
    int i1;
    int i2;
};

#ifdef ENABLE_PACKED
_Static_assert(sizeof(struct my_struct1_packed) ==
               sizeof(struct my_struct2_packed), "Error");
#endif

#undef PACKED
```

Note that you really only need to define ENABLE_PACKED and #include test.h in one file for the static assert to be tested. So you can even just create a dummy.c file which includes test.h twice and have your build compile dummy.c every time but not actually use it in any real release object. That way, all your real .c files do not even need to know about this at all and can just include all header files normally.